# JVM communication library

Tags: java, jvm

NOTE: I did not intend to make this question generic; but rather looking for a very specific tool.

I had used this library a while back, but can't seem to recall the exact library name.
This is how the library behaves:

1. Enable your target JVM to communicate from the external tool (nothing but a command line) by placing a jar in the JVM class path.
2. while the target JVM is running; connect to the target JVM by running the library and once it starts up; you can effectively communicate with the target JVM from the tools command line.
3. You can run scripts (java statements without having to write an entire java program).

Example:
Say my target JVM has an arraylist myList.
I could just write the java statement 
`myList.size()`
in the tools command line; which will provide me the size of the array list myList.

Note that this does not require me to write a whole java class in the target JVM; but rather allows me to write small pieces of code snippet and run them as if I am in the target JVM it self.

I am unable to recall the library name.

I have tried looking at the librares
cajo
AKKA
JUEL

But not sure any of these are the one I was looking for.

Comment: This sounds like you were using JMX from the command line, maybe?

Comment: @AmirAfghani I am pretty sure it's not any JMX library. It was an open source library. Still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it Beanshell.
BeanShell is a small, free, embeddable Java source interpreter with object scripting language features, written in Java. BeanShell dynamically executes standard Java syntax and extends it with common scripting conveniences such as loose types, commands, and method closures like those in Perl and JavaScript. 
Please see link below

[Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html)

Comment: Note: because of its shortness and your new status this is automatically flagged for review.  Normally link-only answers and those which ask questions are discouraged.  However, it does seem to be the type of answer this particular "help me find the library I forgot the name of" question requests.  Still you could change it from acceptable to "good" by adding a sentence or two of summary about beanshell.

Comment: Thanks Chris and user1889970. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had used this sometime back, thanks for reminding me. I will add a line or 2 about BeanShell in my question as well.